# Java - alternative to instanceof?

Tags: java, recursion, nested, instanceof

I have a `Shape` superclass and a `NestedShape` subclass. The `NestedShape` subclass has an ArrayList ('`ShapesList`') of `Shapes` that are nested within it. I need to implement a 'contains' method for `NestedShape`. This method, when given a `Shape` object, should check whether the shape exists in the `NestedShape`'s `ShapeList`. My implementation at the moment is very simple: just call the ArrayList `.contains()` method on `ShapesList`.

However, the 'contains' method I need to implement also has to check that for any `NestedShape` in the `ShapesList`, that shape's `ShapeList` also doesn't contain the shape that is being searched for. The obvious way to me of doing this is to use `instanceof` to check if each `Shape` in the `ShapeList` is a `NestedShape`. Then, I guess I'd recursively call my 'contains' method on it if it was a `NestedShape`. However, I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing this - I've heard that the use of `instanceof` is frowned upon (also, I'm not sure if my idea of using recursion would even work).

Could anyone suggest a better way of solving this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Two separate Lists instead maybe? Perhaps some Parallel arrays (Lists).

Comment: code makes things clearer to understand. Please post some snippet about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use polymorphism:

```
public class Shape {

    public boolean contains(Shape shape) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class NestedShape extends Shape {
    private List<Shape> subShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Shape shape) {
        if (subShapes.contains(shape)) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Shape subShape : subShapes) {
            if (subShape.contains(shape)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. Don't let `NestedShape` extend `Shape`, but handle them seperately.
2. Let all `Shape`s be 'nested'. With single shapes returning always `false` for `contains()`.

Answer (score 1):

If

- the performance of the `contains()` method is your concern and
- `NestedShape` are immutable meaning the list of  nested `Shape` instances once set will never change

then I would suggest a slightly different approach.

Instead of recursively iterating though all the `NestedShapes` you can add a `Set` inside the `Shape` class that will store the references to all the `NestedShape` instances for which it is possible to access this `Shape` instance.